# remove kubernetes service-catalog finalizer with cli

Tags: kubernetes, finalizer, ibm-cloud-private

I'm trying to provision/deprovision service instance/binding from my cloud provider (IBM cloud private), Currently, there is a bug that if the service is not deprovisioned in ICP, that leaves me the orphan service instance on my ICP environment which I can't delete even with force option.
They provide a workaround solution of:

```
kubectl edit ServiceInstance <service-instance-name>
kubectl edit ServiceBinding <service-binding-name>
```

then delete the line:

```
...
finalizers:
    - kubernetes-incubator/service-catalog
...
```

and the orphan service instance/binding will get deleted properly. I'm wondering how to automate this process with bash cli (live edit + delete line + save + exit) or any alternative way.

Answer (score 32):

I'm not sure how this works with the ServiceInstance and ServiceBinding specifically, but you can use [kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/) to update objects in place. As an example:

```
kubectl patch ServiceInstance <service-instance-name> -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}' --type=merge
```

Answer (score 10):

`kubectl patch` is one way. You can also use a [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)/`kubectl` oneliner.

```
kubectl get ServiceInstance <service-instance-name> -o=json | \
jq '.metadata.finalizers = null' | kubectl apply -f -
```