# Istio -- Delete istio-control-plane Process Is Frozen

Tags: kubernetes, istio, azure-aks

I was trying to uninstall and reinstall Istio from k8s cluster following the steps:
[image]

But I made a mistake that I deleted the namespace before deleting the istio-control-plane: `kubectl delete istiooperator istio-control-plane -n istio-system`. Then when I try to delete the `istio-control-plane` again, it froze.

I tried to remove the finalizer using the following steps but it said `Error from server (NotFound): istiooperators.install.istio.io "istio-control-plane" not found`

```
kubectl get istiooperator -n istio-system -o json > output.json
nano output.json # and remove finalizer
kubectl replace --raw "/apis/install.istio.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/istio-system/istiooperators/istio-control-plane/finalize" -f output.json
```

Here is the content of `kubectl get istiooperator -n istio-system -o json`:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "items": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "install.istio.io/v1alpha1",
            "kind": "IstioOperator",
            "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
                    "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"install.istio.io/v1alpha1\",\"kind\":\"IstioOperator\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"istio-control-plane\",\"namespace\":\"istio-system\"},\"spec\":{\"addonComponents\":{\"prometheus\":{\"enabled\":false},\"tracing\":{\"enabled\":false}},\"hub\":\"hub.docker.prod.walmart.com/istio\",\"profile\":\"default\",\"values\":{\"global\":{\"defaultNodeSelector\":{\"beta.kubernetes.io/os\":\"linux\"}}}}}\n"
                },
                "creationTimestamp": "2020-12-05T23:39:34Z",
                "deletionGracePeriodSeconds": 0,
                "deletionTimestamp": "2020-12-07T16:41:41Z",
                "finalizers": [
                ],
                "generation": 2,
                "name": "istio-control-plane",
                "namespace": "istio-system",
                "resourceVersion": "11750055",
                "selfLink": "/apis/install.istio.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/istio-system/istiooperators/istio-control-plane",
                "uid": "fda8ee4f-54e7-45e8-91ec-c328fad1a86f"
            },
            "spec": {
                "addonComponents": {
                    "prometheus": {
                        "enabled": false
                    },
                    "tracing": {
                        "enabled": false
                    }
                },
                "hub": "hub.docker.prod.walmart.com/istio",
                "profile": "default",
                "values": {
                    "global": {
                        "defaultNodeSelector": {
                            "beta.kubernetes.io/os": "linux"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "status": {
                "componentStatus": {
                    "Base": {
                        "status": "HEALTHY"
                    },
                    "IngressGateways": {
                        "status": "HEALTHY"
                    },
                    "Pilot": {
                        "status": "HEALTHY"
                    }
                },
                "status": "HEALTHY"
            }
        }
    ],
    "kind": "List",
    "metadata": {
        "resourceVersion": "",
        "selfLink": ""
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how can I uninstall `istio-control-plane` manually?

Comment: What is your istio version? Have you tried to delete it with `istioctl operator remove`? Have you tried to use `kubectl patch` to patch your istio operator finalizer? There is [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52819428) question about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below command to change istio operator finalizer and delete it, it's a `jq/kubectl` oneliner made by @Rico [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52825601/11977760). I have tried also with `kubectl patch` but it didn't work.

```
kubectl get istiooperator -n istio-system istio-control-plane -o=json | \
jq '.metadata.finalizers = null' | kubectl apply -f -
```

Additionally I have used `istioctl operator remove`

```
istioctl operator remove
Removing Istio operator...
  Removed Deployment:istio-operator:istio-operator.
  Removed Service:istio-operator:istio-operator.
  Removed ServiceAccount:istio-operator:istio-operator.
  Removed ClusterRole::istio-operator.
  Removed ClusterRoleBinding::istio-operator.
✔ Removal complete
```

Results from `kubectl get`

```
kubectl get istiooperator istio-control-plane -n istio-system
Error from server (NotFound): namespaces "istio-system" not found
```